# E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/

Tags: drivers, apt, 18.04, nvidia, cuda

Ubuntu 18.04

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1804/x86_64/ /: /usr/share/keyrings/cuda-archive-keyring.gpg !=
```

My desktop is stuck at black screen "filesystem checking"
I get above error when I run

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-*
```

Please help me with how to fix it

Comment: Did you check if the repo is actually present more than one time, with different `Signed-By` declarations? Please include contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and relevant files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: yes there is single entry only

Comment: Please include it in your question.

Comment: actually, my system is stuck with either the ubuntu logo or filesystem checking screen while logging in. I am accessing terminal in recovery mode when I try to remove cuda it shows above error I want get out of this situation

Comment: Ok please focus on one problem at a time.

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I have only one issue to get from this situation but it looks like due to this I can not get anywhere because I keep on getting this error with sudo apt-get update or any other command that could fix my problem

Answer (score 8):

for me this worked

```
sed -i '/developer\.download\.nvidia\.com\/compute\/cuda\/repos/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
sed -i '/developer\.download\.nvidia\.com\/compute\/machine-learning\/repos/d' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Comment: I am not fully sure what this is doing but worked like a charm!